# Cannot find an Appropriate Loader for FlexboxGrid [ReactJS]

Tags: reactjs, webpack, flexbox

I'm currently trying to use this library http://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/ with my react JS app.

I've currently got my webpack setup and I followed the instructions on flexbox-grid's Github.

However, every time I try to run my app, I get that I don't have an appropriate loader to handle this file type. I've already installed webpack css-loader as well so I'm not sure what else I could be missing.

webpack.config.js

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/App.jsx', 
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'), // this also includes flexboxgrid
        exclude: /flexboxgrid/, // so we are excluding it
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "PokerSiteMaterial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Poker Site",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "Kai Mou",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your webpack config, in addition to your current css rule, as stated in the react-flexbox-grid README...

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css?modules',
  include: /flexboxgrid/,
}
```

You only did part 1 of the process. You told your css loader, which uses  `postcss` and is therefore incompatible with `flexboxgrid`, to ignore `flexboxgrid`, but you did not create a new loader for it.

Basically, `flexboxgrid` needs to be loaded with *only* the css loader. Since, you are using `postcss`, you need to tell your main css rule to ignore it and add the above rule to handle it